# Displaying rows from table into datagridview with matched column value

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a list of string which contain names and a database table what i want to do is to display the rows from the table in datagridview. All rows which contain the name column value same as any of the list item will be displayed into datagrid view.I wrote the code for this using for loop but it is showing only last matched row in datagridview.

```
DBConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=FacesDatabase.mdb";
DBConnection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = DBConnection;

for(i=0;i<MatchName.ToArray().Length;i++)
{
      string query = "Select FaceID,FaceName,RollNo,FaceImage from " + tableName + " where FaceName='" + MatchName[i].ToString() + "'";
      command.CommandText = query;
      OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
      DataTable dt=new DataTable();
      da.Fill(dt);
      dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
}

DBConnection.Close();
```

Comment: 'cause you assign only the last results as datasource.

Comment: Yes but i want all matched rows from table into datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **IN** SQL key word:

```
DBConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=FacesDatabase.mdb";
DBConnection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = DBConnection;
string query = "Select FaceID,FaceName,RollNo,FaceImage from " + tableName + " where FaceName IN ('"+ string.Join("','",MatchName.ToArray())+ "')";
command.CommandText = query;
OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
DBConnection.Close();
```

In your example what you're doing is querying the db for each "MatchName" (whatever that is) and for every resultset you're getting back you're assigning it as the datagrid's datasource. Therefore you're only seeing the last resultset since you're overwriting previous results.

Using the **IN** key word you're only hitting the db once and binding the grid to the data source once.

I also recommend using command parameters instead of building your query they way you are using string concatenation.

Comment: This exception is coming No value given for one or more required parameters. when i changed this line                                                         (" + string.Join(",", MatchName.ToArray()) + ")     into this                          (' " + string.Join(",", MatchName.ToArray()) + " ') then expection is removed but nothing displayed into datagridview only column name displayed

Comment: the select statement is not returning any row it returns 0 zero.I checked it by using following query.                                                                    "Select count(*) from " + tableName + " where FaceName IN ('" + string.Join(",",MatchName.ToArray()) + "')";

Comment: finally it worked the problem is with thw querythe string.join function is not taking the array item in proper format for query after modifying the query it worked.Thanks a lot for the help,                   string query = "Select * from " + tableName + " where FaceName IN ('"+ string.Join("','",MatchName.ToArray())+ "')";

Comment: Glad to be of help. You're right about the missing single quote. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your gridview datasource. You can also do something like,

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
for (i = 0; i < MatchName.ToArray().Length; i++)
{
    string query = "Select FaceID,FaceName,RollNo,FaceImage from " + tableName + " where FaceName='" + MatchName[i].ToString() + "'";
    command.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
    {
        DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(x => dt2.ImportRow(x));
        dt = dt2;
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: It is throwing exceptionNo row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.

Comment: Now exception coming at this dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows);       Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

Comment: Sure i will try this too